# Magento 2: How to get product prices?

Tags: magento2, product, product-prices

How do I get Netto(without tax) and Brutto(with tax) prices in magento2 inside the custom block?

I try to show the 2 prices.

Answer (score 2):

To display/show product price including tax amount, you need to do some configuration settings.

**1. Create Tax Rule**

You need to create tax rules (Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Rules). For this, you can refer to different tutorials available over the internet on creating Tax rules.

**2. Assign Tax Rule to Product**

Then, you need to assign the Tax rule to the product.

– Edit product (Catalog -> Manage Products)
– Go to ‘Prices’ tab
– Select your Tax rule from the ‘Tax Class’ select box
– Save the product

**3. Configuration Settings to show Product Price including Tax**

Now, go to configuration settings (System -> Configuration -> SALES -> Tax -> Price Display Settings -> Display Product Prices in Catalog).

You have three options there. To show product price:

a) Excluding Tax
b) Including Tax
c) Including and Excluding Tax

That’s all. Now, you should be able to see the frontend product price as per your configuration setting.

### **Programmatically**

I believe that you are referring to `Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`
You could use something like

```
    $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount()
```

This gets you the price with no tax into store currency

this code should work for all product types **with tax**::

```
    $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getAmount()
```

is the price including tax (that adds Weee FPT price as well if you use that)
You can look at the format of `$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()`
it has all your needed information there like discounts, adjustments, tax values if more.. etc..

***Update***

> **Code Example**

```
echo "<pre>";
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product_id = 15;
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
// get excluding price
$priceData = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getBaseAmount();
//print_r($priceData);

echo "Excluding Price : " . $priceData . "<br/>";
// get including price
$priceData = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount();
echo "Including Price : " . $priceData . "<br/>";
```